# Reset a table data with an observable as its source

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have an observable that fills a table like this:

```
 <table class="table table-borderless" style="width:44%;" *ngIf="(borrowers_main_data$ | async) as borrowers_main_data">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="8%">CDI:</td>
            <td>
              <strong>{{ borrowers_main_data.Cdi }}</strong>
```

And this is the code that fills the table:

```
public borrowers_main_data$ = this.service.cdiVariable$.pipe(
switchMap(cdiVariable => {return this.dataSource.getCustomer(cdiVariable).pipe(
  catchError(error => {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      this.errorMsg = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      this.errorMsg = `Error: ${error.message}`;
    }
    return of({} as Customer);
  }))
}));
```

The problem is that in the case of a second search (after a successful one) that returns the Observable of the empty object the table stays populated with the previous data.

Comment: what is the expected behavior? if you don't want the table to show up anymore, `return of(null as Customer)`

Comment: From the code I see in code it should work as expected (values from table should be removed, but the table itself should stay (if({}) is truthy). You can check what's going on, by adding following code in template `{{borrowers_main_data$ | async | json}}` and see what is the state of the observable